# Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation in C#

Tags: c#

I am using BackGround Worker for Loading data from DB(MS Access).
In my Form_Load i use:

```
 bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

In my DoWork event I laod the data from DB

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        int iResult = OpenDB();
        if (iResult != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error in Opening DataBase", Constants.TITLE);
            return ;
        }
        DataSet ds = GetAllUserInfo();
        e.Result = ds;


    }
```

And in My RunWorkerCompleted i assign data to DataGridView.

```
    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        dgUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = e.Result; 


    }
```

//Error Comes here after executing above code

```
[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new frmMain());
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What is "above error" exactly. Any exception (including the complete stacktrace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SyncronizationContext mechanism for UI update . Example here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx

1 .Have this as a global object :

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
```

1. Instantiate the object "synchronizationContext" on Form_Load event :

   synchronizationContext = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
2. Modify bgw_RonWorkerCompleted to :

   private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {

   ```
         synchronizationContext.Post(new SendOrPostCallback(
          delegate
          {
              dgUsers.DatSource =e.Result as DataSet;
          }), null);
   ```

   }

Comment: have you tried to cast e.Result to Cells[0].Value type ? Your e.Result is a DataSet object . You can do this dgUsers.DataSource =  e.Result as DataSet

Comment: DataSet ds = e.Result as DataSet ;           
            try
            {
                dgUsers.DataSource = ds;                                    
                for (int iCounter = 0; iCounter < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count ; iCounter++)
                {                   
                    AddToList(iCounter, ds);
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

Comment: I have 2 Rows in my dataset but when i try to loop as above it gives Exception "Index out of range" for second record

Comment: @user662285 what does the "AddToList(iCounter, ds); " method ? There should be the problem . .

Answer (score 2):

This happens when an exception happens on another thread.

Check that exceptions inner exception to find the real exception that was thrown by your `DoWork` method..

Answer (score 1):

You should'nt handle the exception in bgw_DoWork.

```
 private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
            OpenDB();
            e.Result = GetAllUserInfo();
 }
```

instead you have to check the Error Property of RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs back on the UI thread.

```
 private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (e.Error ==null)
        dgUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = e.Result; 
     else
       MessageBox.Show("Error in Opening DataBase", Constants.TITLE);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a cross-thread operation :  the `RunWorkerCompleted` isn't raised in the UI thread, resulting in a cross-thread operation on `.Value`. Could you try this :

```
                    private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
                    if (this.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted, sender, e);
                        return;
                    }
                    dgUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = e.Result; 
                }
```